# What is AVG I/O request for normal EC2 Instance with web server on Amazon AWS

Tags: file-io, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have an Amazon `Ec2` instance with EBS Volume.

`Standard EBS Volumes are billed $0.10 per 1 million I/O requests`

Now I am not able to guess how much is the normal I/O request for normal server. And in the max case how large it can be.

How can I get the metrics or stats from somewhere so that I can see how much max is for very busy server so i can roughly see how max i can get?

I would like to know this so that I can find some way of controlling it. Presently, I have one public site with not much traffic but I want to know if traffic increases then how much max it can go.

Comment: This is impossible to predict. All you can do is set it up and measure the results. Alot of factors can affect if an operation goes to the disk instead of a memory cache.

Comment: It will never get to a prohibitively expensive number. Lets assume that it will be a few dollars at worst. You should maybe be trying to monetize your site to make a dime per million i/o's if it gets to be a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about price predictability you may consider switching to a PIOPS volume over a standard EBS volume. From the [EBS web site](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/):

> With Provisioned IOPS volumes, you are also charged by the amount you
>   provision in IOPS (input/output operations per second) X the
>   percentage of days you provision for the month.

The easily predictable billing model of a PIOPS volume (not to mention their performance) can make them very attractive for certain workloads.

Comment: That's in addition to the charge per million I/O's, is it not?

Comment: According to the EBS Web site, that isn't in addition to the per million I/O charges. http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/

Rather it's charged based on what you provisioned, rather than what you used.

Comment: +1 you're absolutely right; I have been misinterpreting that all along, thinking the two were additive.